# To use Class or not to use Class , many objects

Tags: c#, class, data-structures

my program (console app) is basically reading a very big csv file and process it. there are columns in the file that I feel like can be grouped together and bestserved in class
for example the first line is title, second line onward are the values. each column has this structure. so I need to group title, location of the column and values. easiest is to create a class

this is what the data look like:

```
title1, title2, title3, ...
1,1,2, ...
20,30,5000,...
.
.
.


class tt 
{
  string title;
  int column;
  List<int> val = new List<int>();

}
```

but the problem is there are some 1,000 columns , which translate to 1,000 objects. is this a good approach? not sure?

Comment: Use [LINQ To CSV](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25133/LINQ-to-CSV-library), or else try to find something that maps your CSV stuff into proper classes.

Comment: As an aside, 1,000 objects is not very many by modern computing standards. You should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

A class with 1000 members would sound.... unusual, to be blunt. Since it is unlikely that the code is going to be referring to any of those by name, I would say it would be self-defeating to create members per-value. But for "should I create a class" - well, you don't have many options - it certainly would make a **very** bad struct. Actually, I suspect this may be a fair scenario for `DataTable` - it is not something I usually recommend, but for the data you are describing, it will probably do the job fine. Yes, it has overheads - but it optimises away a number of issues - for example, by storing data internally in *typed columns* (rather than rows, as you might expect), it avoids having to box all the values during storage (although they still tend to get boxed during access, those boxes are collected during gen-0, so are cheap).

"Thousands" are low numbers in most computing scenarios.

Note: if you actually mean 1000 rows, and the columns are actually sane (say, less than 50, all meaningful), then I would say "sure, create a class that maps the data" - for example something like:

```
class Customer {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    //...
}
```

There are several tools that can help you read this from SCV into the objects, typically into a `List<Customer>` or `IEnumerable<Customer>`.

Answer (score 0):

> but the problem is there are some 1,000 columns , which translate to 1,000 objects. is this a good approach

**yes** translating to 1000 objects (if you need them) should not bother you.

but, for so many columns creating classes is hell lot of work. I won't do that unless it is absolutely necessary. You can use DataTable.

Answer (score 0):

If your file is a big CSV file I suggest that load them on a DataSet. I dont see any benefit in using a class for each column

The CSV looks like a transposed regular data table, therefore each column is actully a row

Comment: this is a console app , not windows form app

Comment: @JohnRyann DataSet is a Class does not depend on the user interface . therefore you can then output the contents of the DataSet with Console.WriteLine(...) or access its contents with the Tables[i]